# Как распараллелить код, дабы он выполнялся эффективнее?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, proxy

Вообщем, я сделал прокси чекер, но теперь встал вопрос: как распараллелить выполнение кода, повысив эффективность выполнения программы. Буду очень рад, если вы не просто мне укажите, что надо использовать, а конкретно приведете изменённый код. Я вас тогда просто расцелую!
Вот исходный код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
 
 
class RegistriUAAccs
{
    
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите ссылку на файл TXT, где хранятся ваши прокси.");
        string fm = Console.ReadLine();
 
        //Объява переменных 
        string reader = null;
        string writetoprox = null;
        bool checkadd = false;
 
        //Объява массивов.
        ArrayList msproxy = new ArrayList();
        //
 
 
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@fm))
        {
            reader = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        // Console.WriteLine(reader);
        // Этот цикл foreach считывает прокси в msproxy без пробелов, \t , \n. Только прокси и порт считывает.
        foreach (char r in reader)
        {
            if (r != ' ' & r != '\r' & r != '\n')
            {
                writetoprox += r;
                checkadd = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (checkadd == false)
                {
                    msproxy.Add(writetoprox);
                }
                checkadd = true;
                writetoprox = null;
            }
        }
        int cv = 0;
        // Тут try / catch оборачивается в for для того, чтобы переходить к следующей прокси, если прошлая оказалась недействительна.
        for (int j = 0; j < msproxy.Count; j++)
        {
            try
            {
                // Чек прокси
                for (int i = j; i < msproxy.Count; i++)
                {
                    cv = i;
                    WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(msproxy[i].ToString(), true);
                    HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("https://www.google.com/");
                    req.Proxy = proxy;
                    req.Timeout = 3000;
                    var Response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                    var RespString = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream("Good.txt", FileMode.Append);
                    using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(fs))
                    {
                        write.WriteLine(msproxy[cv]);
                    }
                   
                    Console.WriteLine(msproxy[cv] + " ВЕРНО!!!!!!");
                }
            }
            // Если прокси не рабочая, то вылавливаем это, а затем записываем в файл и выводим известие об этом на экран.
            catch (System.Net.WebException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
 
 
                FileStream fs = new FileStream("Bad.txt", FileMode.Append);
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
                {
                    string proxys = msproxy[cv].ToString();
                    sw.WriteLine(proxys);
                }
               
 
                Console.WriteLine(msproxy[cv] + " Неверно!");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
 
 
 
}
```

Comment: Немного подправил некоторые ошибки в коде и в тексте. Заранее прошу прощение, если что-то не так.

Comment: Забудьте про `HttpWebRequest`, он в C# устарел! Также, научитесь использовать `async/await`, а также, предположу, что это дубликат.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ В каком смысле дубликат?

Comment: типа такой вопрос уже задавался и ответ на него можно найти на сервисе

Comment: @Andrew, уже понял, :D

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Жаль, что на всех SO нельзя выпилить все вопросы и ответы, в которых упоминается `HttpWebRequest`. :)

Comment: @aepot Ну это было бы лишним, ибо в некоторых случаях он еще является единственным и неповторимым. Не будете вы ведь переписывать уже готовый проект под `HttpClient`, когда надо исправить всего 1 недостаток. Тут бы плашку какую-то, как вон атрибут `obsolete` в c#, но это явно не будут делать ради таких целей)

Comment: @aepot Откуда такая ненависть к этому классу? :D Или по-вашему новичкам надо сразу окунаться в какие-то сложные для понимания классы.

Comment: @CsHarpUser Почитайте документацию, это рекомендация Microsoft, они его уже давно не развивают (а также все, что на нем базируется), он попросту заброшен. Мы лишь следуем их советам и предупреждаем про это других.

Comment: А как будешь относиться у нему, если ты когда-то его использовал, потому что нашел на StackOverflow, 2 месяца мучался, не мог понять, почему все так медленно работает, перешел на `HttpClient`, выучил `async/await`, и теперь данные из API грузятся не 5 минут, а 10 секунд. `HttpWebRequest` убил очень много моего времени, я его терпеть не могу. И да, код, который был 200 строк, стал 50 после переработки, так что неизвестно, что из этого сложнее.

Comment: @aepot Тогда спору нет, согласен.

Comment: `if (r != ' ' & r != '\r' & r != '\n')` - посмотрите примеры использования `string.Split()`. Весь этот блок можно в одну не очень длинную строку переписать. И посмотрите, чем отличается `&&` от `&` и `||` от `|`. `ArrayList` можно заменить на `List<string>`, тогда не придется вызывать `.ToString()`. Еще метод `File.WriteAllLines()` вам может пригодиться.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо большое, что подметили, но на данный момент мне надо разобраться с параллельной проверкой прокси и с потоками, а потом уже переходить к улучшению кода.

Comment: `reader = sr.ReadToEnd();` - уберите `StreamReader` и используйте `reader = File.ReadAllText(fm)`.

Comment: По поводу "потом разберусь" - то что я предлагаю, будет раз в 50 быстрее работать, чем ваша посимвольная сборка строк. Вы же хотели ускориться.

Comment: @aepot Нет, я тогда неправильно выразил свою мысль. Моё дело ни сколько сделать реальную программу, которая быстро работает ( хотя и это тоже ), а и еще проверить себя на то, как я помню выученный материал, а также попрактиковаться с использованием потоков ( ибо, как выяснилось сейчас, я эту тему не очень усвоил ).

Comment: [BeginGetResponse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_HttpWebRequest_BeginGetResponse_System_AsyncCallback_System_Object_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Моё дело ни сколько сделать реальную программу, которая быстро работает ( хотя и это тоже ), а и еще проверить себя на то, как я помню выученный материал

Ну тогда вот вам для разминки.

```cs
static async Task Main()
{
    string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-YYYY_HH-mm");
    Console.WriteLine("Введите ссылку на файл TXT, где хранятся ваши прокси.");
    string fm = Console.ReadLine();

    string proxies = File.ReadAllText(fm);
    string[] msproxy = proxies.Split(new[] { ' ', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    string url = "https://www.google.com/";
           
    using (StreamWriter swGood = new StreamWriter($"{date}_Good.txt"))
    using (StreamWriter swBad = new StreamWriter($"{date}_Bad.txt"))
    {
        foreach (string proxy in msproxy)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy, true) };
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler) { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3) })
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        swGood.WriteLine(proxy);
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} Верно!", proxy);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        swBad.WriteLine(proxy);
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} Неверно!", proxy);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                swBad.WriteLine(proxy);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Ошибка! {1}", proxy, ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

По поводу потоков, нужно знать, .NET Core или Framework. Нужно настроить нормальное закрытие сокетов после запроса, иначе компьютеру может стать плохо. Тогда можно будет распараллелить. Но то что я показал выше, уже должно значительно быстрее работать.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Люблю вас! Целую!

Comment: Кстати, насчёт HttpClient 'a вы оказались правы. Код действительно стал проще.

Comment: @CsHarpUser ну я здесь вообще не читаю ответ от гугла, а только заголовки ответа, пометьте себе, читать ответ вот так `string html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`. Так что при нормальной работе +1 строчка :)

Comment: @CsHarpUser матчасть - [`HttpClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8), [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async)