# Как разграничить доступ к списку в Parallels.For

Tags: c#

В многопотоке делаю гет-запросы. Результат пихаю в список. Дальше в монопольном режиме хочу запихнуть данные в БД. Почему то `lock` не даёт монопольный доступ к `InsertRowsToDB`, так как у меня в БД дублируются данные.

```
var rows = new List<string>();
Object locker = new Object();
Parallel.For(0,urls.Count, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100}, (i) =>
{
   var data = GetRequest(urls[i]);
   lock(locker)
     {
       rows.Add(data);
       
       if (rows.Count>=100)
       {
           InsertRowsToDB(rows); 
           rows.Clear();
       }
     }
});
```

Comment: Вам точно надо многопоток, а не [асихронщину](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1188585/213987)?

Comment: Проблема за пределами показанного кода. Виноват здесь не лок, а скорее сам метод `InsertRowsToDB`, возможно он асинхронный.

Comment: Например можно пофиксить вот так `InsertRowsToDB(rows.ToList());` - передавать копию списка, чтобы гарантировать, что она не будет модифицирована, пока идет запись.

Comment: @AK в многопотоке идут гет запросы для ускорения

Comment: "так как у меня в БД дублируются данные" - ну и что?

Comment: @Igor урлов у меня 1к, данных в бд появляется 2-3к. Они дублируются

Comment: Покажите ваш метод `InsertRowsToDB`

Comment: Но у вас же по логике и после цикла должен быть вызов `InsertRowsToDB(rows)`, иначе вы потеряете часть данных (до 99 записей). Приводите уж весь код, имеющий отношение к делу.

Comment: `в многопотоке идут гет запросы для ускорения` для асинхронныйх вызовов не нужен многопоток, но они вполне могут выполняться одновременно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не вдаваться в подробности того, что вероятно у вас неверно простроена работа по сети и с БД, то можете попробовать вот такой вариант решения.

```cs
var rows = new List<string>();
Object locker = new Object();
Parallel.For(0,urls.Count, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100}, (i) =>
{
   var data = GetRequest(urls[i]);
   lock(locker)
   {
       rows.Add(data);
       
       if (rows.Count>=100)
       {
           InsertRowsToDB(rows); 
           rows = new List<string>();
       }
   }
});
InsertRowsToDB(rows);
```

В этом случае, список, переданный в метод `InsertRowsToDB` не будет изменен после передачи.

А происходит это потому что возврат из метода `InsertRowsToDB` происходит раньше, чем сам метод завершит работу. Скорее всего, он асинхронный, либо содержит асинхронные вызовы, завершения которых вы не ожидаете, а выполняете возврат из метода.